# AWS notification on exceeding limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch, price

I just started using AWS services. I want to receive notifications if any service  usage exceeds limit. After searching for the options I found that same can be achieved suing AWS Cloudwatch alarm and AWS Limit Monitor using AWS CloudFormation. My question is, will i be charged if i use these services to receive notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can setup all kinds of notifications to keep a handle on what you are being billed, but that doesn't stop you from actually getting billed if you exceed your limits.

For example I have alerts to notify me when I reach 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% of my typical monthly spend - so I roughly should get one notification each week - but a lot can happen between when you get sent the notification, and when you take action - especially if, for example, someone got access to your account and started crypto-mining on some big ec2 instances.